# Can invocation of nehek heal a lone character?

Tags: warhammer-fantasy

Can the invocation of nehek spell, vampire counts, heal a lone character?

The spell says unit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Yes.**

According to Forming Units (8th Edition Rulebook, pg 5), *"A unit usually consists of several models that have banded together, but **a single, powerful model such as a lone character**, a chariot or a Dragon, a war machine and its crew, and so on, **are also considered to be a unit**."*

Everything is a unit, even a lone character.

Though bear in mind the rules for Invocation of Nehek. *"Models with the Vampiric, Ethereal or Large Target special rules can never regain more than 1 Wound per successful casting."* (Vampire Counts 8th Ed, pg 60). So a lone Vampire for example will only gain a single wound.